# How to check for compile errors before compiling with CodeDom

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, codedom, .net-assembly, roslyn

I'm using the CodeDom to allow custom scripts (C#) to be run in an application I'm creating.
While writing the script I would like to be able to check for compile errors. The code gets added to and compiled into memory at a much later time and run so i don't want the assembly compiled while writing the script to remain in memory.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Is it possible to remove the assembly from memory after compiling?

```
private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> assemblyNames = new List<string> { };
    List<string> code = new List<string> { };
    foreach (string str in GetCompileParameters())
            if (!assemblyNames.Contains(str))
                assemblyNames.Add(str);
    code.AddRange(GetScriptCode());

    CodeDomProvider provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerParameters mCompileParams = new CompilerParameters(assemblyNames.ToArray());
    mCompileParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
    mCompileParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library /optimize";

    CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(mCompileParams, code.ToArray());
    if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        string error = "The following compile error occured:\r\n";
        foreach (CompilerError err in results.Errors)
            error += "File: " + err.FileName + "; Line (" + err.Line + ") - " + err.ErrorText + "\n";
        MessageBox.Show(error);
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("No errors found");

    //Need to Remove assembly here
}
```

**Update:**

Thank you Keith.

For anyone interested this is the new code i'm using with Roslyn

```
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;

...

private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> assemblyNames = new List<string> { }; 
        foreach (string str in GetCompileParameters())
                if (!assemblyNames.Contains(str))
                    assemblyNames.Add(str);

        SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(mScenario.GetScriptCode("ScriptName"));
        Compilation com = Compilation.Create("Script");
        com = com.AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(Object).Assembly.Location)); // Add reference mscorlib.dll
        com = com.AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location)); // Add reference System.Core.dll
        com = com.AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(typeof(System.Net.Cookie).Assembly.Location)); // Add reference System.dll
        foreach (string str in assemblyNames)
            com = com.AddReferences(new AssemblyFileReference(str)); // Add additional references
        com = com.AddSyntaxTrees(tree);

        Diagnostic[] dg = com.GetDiagnostics().ToArray();
        if (dg.Length > 0)
        {
            string error = "The following compile error occured:\r\n";
            foreach (Diagnostic d in dg)
                error += "Info: " + d.Info + "\n";
            MessageBox.Show(error, "Compile Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        } else {
            MessageBox.Show("No errors found.", "Code Compiler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the newly released http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how to do this with the [Roslyn](http://msdn.com/Roslyn) CTP, take a look at http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/10/c-sharp-syntax-checker-aspnet-roslyn.html